# not able to reach protected webpage after login using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Hy! I have tried many things and read a lot in the docs but i don't get it.

At first here is my code:

```
import requests

payload = {'name': 'Super',
           'password': 'Superad'}

s = requests.Session()
requ1 = s.post('http://someurl/auth', data=payload, verify=False)

requ2 = s.get('https://someurl/server', verify=False)
print(requ2.text)
```

My first problem:

After my first request (requ1) i get the status code 200 and everything is fine. But when i try the next request, whitch is a by login protected site, i only get the html page from the http://someurl/auth site, the login page.The second request (requ2) also returns a status code 200. I really don't know whats wrong with my code.

My second issue:

I really don't get it how can i get the data from the site with json. Content type is text/html. or is it even possible to get the data in json?

I'm sorry for this stupid question but i really don't know how to solve my problems. Thanks in advance for any help or tips!

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: Sorry but i can't. Its a private VM based on VMware.

Comment: Then only you can debug, check the post request in your browser using dev tools, firebug etc..

Comment: Thanks for the tipp! I will try it!